# Best way to get data from database

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a doubt. I need to get the data from the sever twice every time when I load a page, one to render the HTML and another one to get the data for client side (javascript).

So I don't know exactly what it's the best way and fastest. I was trying to implement a session object and store the data once using joinedload loading technique. When the data is in the client side, to kill the session object.

Another one it's to call the database twice.

I don't know which one is faster and better because I don't know if the database or server stores the first call in memory. If so it's not like to call the database twice, right?

And if the second choice is better which loading technique (joinedload, eagerload or subqueryload) is better to use.

Every call could be a bunch of data.

Any help could be really useful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what the question is, perhaps you could rephrase it. Also, are you sure you have a performance problem? Premature optimization is the root of all evil, as they say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure about all this stuff you asked, so I'll try 2 different scenarios.

- If the data you need to display the html and data needed for the javascript is the *same* - you're doing it *very wrong*. All you need to do is to query the db only for the html, then structure the data needed for javascript in hidden fields, then, on client side, query the html's hidden fields with javascript and use the data onward.
- If the data sets are different than you'll probably need an ajax request from the client side *after* the html is displayed. That is, an additional http request. I say you close the db connection after the first call, and then reopen again with the next http request. Every http request is on its own, you'll need to take care with opening/closing connections inside a *single* request. [That is, if you don't use pooling, but that is another issue]

Comment: Yes, I agree. I hadn't thought about doing it in that way, but I already had found out that approach.